# Видео на фоне блока <div>

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Как поставить видео на фон определенного блока?

Например, есть блок  (который является адаптивным) с определенными блоками и тегами. Как сделать так, чтобы на его background'е было определенное видео?

Comment: `<video>` http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp  с `autoplay`   или `canvas` в котором будет видео из `<video>` с `autoplay`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Просто положить блок поверх видео. Или видео в этот блок, но с отрицательным z-index'ом.

```css
div {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  height: 220px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
}

video {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <video width="400" autoplay muted playsinline>
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  </video>
  А тут какой-то текст поверх видео.
  <br>
  <a href=http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp>И даже ссылка</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Не получается, я использую отрицательный индекс, но оно кидает видео отдельным блоком, остальной материал идет снизу ( а нужно, чтобы видео было на фоне, желательно адаптивное).

Comment: @SvArt713, всё получается. Ответ дополнен.

Comment: @Qwertiy извините, данный вариант коректно отоборажается на айфонах? если указать только видео mp4? или надо обязательно ogg ставить?

Comment: @dantelol, не знаю, проверь. Подозреваю, там ещё и от кодека может зависеть, а не только от формата.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то использовал такое решение - https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/knqyK

Пример с фоном страницы в целом, но это можно сделать и для отдельного блока.

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("bgvid");
var pauseButton = document.querySelector("#polina button");

if (window.matchMedia('(prefers-reduced-motion)').matches) {
    vid.removeAttribute("autoplay");
    vid.pause();
    pauseButton.innerHTML = "Paused";
}

function vidFade() {
  vid.classList.add("stopfade");
}

vid.addEventListener('ended', function()
{
// only functional if "loop" is removed 
vid.pause();
// to capture IE10
vidFade();
}); 


pauseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  vid.classList.toggle("stopfade");
  if (vid.paused) {
    vid.play();
    pauseButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
  } else {
    vid.pause();
    pauseButton.innerHTML = "Paused";
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #000; 
}
video { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 background: url('//demosthenes.info/assets/images/polina.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 1s opacity;
}
.stopfade { 
   opacity: .5;
}

#polina { 
  font-family: Agenda-Light, Agenda Light, Agenda, Arial Narrow, sans-serif;
  font-weight:100; 
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  color: white;
  padding: 2rem;
  width: 33%;
  margin:2rem;
  float: right;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 0;
  letter-spacing: .3rem;
}
#polina button { 
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  padding: .4rem;
  border: none; 
  margin: 1rem auto; 
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.23);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px; 
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .3s background;
}
#polina button:hover { 
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  padding: .5rem;
  transition: .6s background; 
}
a:hover{
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) { 
  div{width:70%;} 
}
@media screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {
  html { background: url(https://thenewcode.com/assets/images/polina.jpg) #000 no-repeat center center fixed; }
  #bgvid { display: none; }
}
```

```html
<video poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/polina.jpg" id="bgvid" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
  <!-- WCAG general accessibility recommendation is that media such as background video play through only once. Loop turned on for the purposes of illustration; if removed, the end of the video will fade in the same way created by pressing the "Pause" button  -->
<source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div id="polina">
<h1>Polina</h1>
<p>filmed by Alexander Wagner 2011
<p><a href="http://thenewcode.com/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video">original article</a>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur porta dictum turpis, eu mollis justo gravida ac. Proin non eros blandit, rutrum est a, cursus quam. Nam ultricies, velit ac suscipit vehicula, turpis eros sollicitudin lacus, at convallis mauris magna non justo. Etiam et suscipit elit. Morbi eu ornare nulla, sit amet ornare est. Sed vehicula ipsum a mattis dapibus. Etiam volutpat vel enim at auctor.</p>
<p>Aenean pharetra convallis pellentesque. Vestibulum et metus lectus. Nunc consectetur, ipsum in viverra eleifend, erat erat ultricies felis, at ultricies mi massa eu ligula. Suspendisse in justo dapibus metus sollicitudin ultrices id sed nisl.</p>
<button>Pause</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю на сколько хороший пример, ставите блок с position: relative;
в нем ставитье блок с position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom:0; 
к примеру
width: 100%; height: 17hv; потом этот блок разместится вовсю ширину блока но не будет мешать остальным ставьте там что хотите.

вот как то так: https://jsfiddle.net/07tne9kp/

```
<div class="hasvideo">
  <video autoplay  poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/polina.jpg" id="bgvid" loop>
  <!-- WCAG general accessibility recommendation is that media such as background video play through only once. Loop turned on for the purposes of illustration; if removed, the end of the video will fade in the same way created by pressing the "Pause" button  -->
<source src="//demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="//demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<div class="text">
My text for this video;
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: не работает ваш пример !