# Как использовать canvas фоном для div

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, html

Не могу разобраться, как использовать canvas  как background для страницы или div? Все попытки приводят к тому, что canvas перекрывает всё содержимое.

```js
"use strict"; {
  const perlin = {
    init() {
      this.p = new Uint8Array(512);
      this.reset();
    },
    reset() {
      const p = new Uint8Array(256);
      for (let i = 0; i < 256; i++) p[i] = i;
      for (let i = 255; i > 0; i--) {
        const n = Math.floor((i + 1) * Math.random());
        [p[i], p[n]] = [p[n], p[i]];
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < 512; i++) this.p[i] = p[i & 255];
    },
    lerp(t, a, b) {
      return a + t * (b - a);
    },
    grad2d(i, x, y) {
      const v = (i & 1) === 0 ? x : y;
      return (i & 2) === 0 ? -v : v;
    },
    noise2d(x2d, y2d) {
      const X = Math.floor(x2d) & 255;
      const Y = Math.floor(y2d) & 255;
      const x = x2d - Math.floor(x2d);
      const y = y2d - Math.floor(y2d);
      const fx = (3 - 2 * x) * x * x;
      const fy = (3 - 2 * y) * y * y;
      const p0 = this.p[X] + Y;
      const p1 = this.p[X + 1] + Y;
      return this.lerp(
        fy,
        this.lerp(
          fx,
          this.grad2d(this.p[p0], x, y),
          this.grad2d(this.p[p1], x - 1, y)
        ),
        this.lerp(
          fx,
          this.grad2d(this.p[p0 + 1], x, y - 1),
          this.grad2d(this.p[p1 + 1], x - 1, y - 1)
        )
      );
    }
  };
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  const canvas = {
    init() {
      this.elem = document.getElementById("canvas");
      document.body.appendChild(this.elem);
      this.width = this.elem.width = this.elem.offsetWidth;
      this.height = this.elem.height = this.elem.offsetHeight;
      return this.elem.getContext("2d");
    }
  };
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  const webgl = {
    init(canvas, options) {
      this.elem = document.createElement("canvas");
      this.gl = (
        this.elem.getContext("webgl", options) ||
        this.elem.getContext("experimental-webgl", options)
      );
      if (!this.gl) return false;
      const vertexShader = this.gl.createShader(this.gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
      this.gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, `
    precision highp float;
    attribute vec3 aPosition;
    uniform vec2 uResolution;
    void main() {
     gl_PointSize = 1.0;
     gl_Position = vec4(
      ( aPosition.x / uResolution.x * 2.0) - 1.0, 
      (-aPosition.y / uResolution.y * 2.0) + 1.0, 
      0.0,
      1.0
     );
    }`);
      this.gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
      const fragmentShader = this.gl.createShader(this.gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
      this.gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, `
    precision highp float;
    void main() {
     gl_FragColor = vec4(0.07, 0.0, 0.68, 1.0);
    }`);
      this.gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
      const program = this.gl.createProgram();
      this.gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
      this.gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
      this.gl.linkProgram(program);
      this.gl.useProgram(program);
      this.aPosition = this.gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aPosition");
      this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.aPosition);
      this.positionBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();
      this.elem.width = canvas.width;
      this.elem.height = canvas.height;
      const uResolution = this.gl.getUniformLocation(program, "uResolution");
      this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(uResolution);
      this.gl.uniform2f(uResolution, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      this.gl.viewport(
        0,
        0,
        this.gl.drawingBufferWidth,
        this.gl.drawingBufferHeight
      );
      return this.gl;
    },
    drawBuffer(data, num) {
      this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.positionBuffer);
      this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.aPosition, 2, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
      this.gl.bufferData(
        this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
        data,
        this.gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW
      );
      this.gl.drawArrays(this.gl.GL_POINTS, 0, num);
    }
  };
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  const ctx = canvas.init();
  const gl = webgl.init(canvas, {
    alpha: false,
    stencil: false,
    antialias: false,
    depth: false,
  });
  perlin.init();
  const nParticles = 30000;
  const velocities = new Float32Array(nParticles * 2);
  const particles = new Float32Array(nParticles * 2);
  let frame = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < nParticles; i++) {
    const p = i * 2;
    particles[p + 0] = Math.random() * canvas.width;
    particles[p + 1] = Math.random() * canvas.height;
  }
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  const run = () => {
    requestAnimationFrame(run);
    frame++;
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.025)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
    for (let i = 0; i < nParticles; i++) {
      const p = i * 2;
      let n = 80 * perlin.noise2d(particles[p + 0] * 0.001, particles[p + 1] * 0.001);
      velocities[p + 0] += 0.1 * Math.cos(n);
      velocities[p + 1] += 0.1 * Math.sin(n);
      particles[p + 0] += (velocities[p + 0] *= 0.99);
      particles[p + 1] += (velocities[p + 1] *= 0.99);
      particles[p + 0] = (canvas.width + particles[p + 0]) % canvas.width;
      particles[p + 1] = (canvas.height + particles[p + 1]) % canvas.height;
    }
    webgl.drawBuffer(particles, nParticles);
    if (frame > 30) ctx.drawImage(webgl.elem, 0, 0);
  };
  requestAnimationFrame(run);
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ["click", "touchdown"].forEach(event => {
    document.addEventListener(event, e => perlin.reset(), false);
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483224/178988 - так же

Comment: Пробовал не помогает. К вопросу привёл код.

Comment: Этот код никак не связан с кодом из моего ответа...

Comment: Так быть может причина в том, что вы дали как ответ ссылку не связанную с моим кодом?) 
Я лишь добавил скрипт самого canvas.

И решение уже нашёл кстати:
Нужно было поместить всё в контейнер, указать top, left для фона, и дать контейнеру position: relative и z-index  выше, чем у фона.

Comment: Всё там так же. Неужели сложно video на canvas заменить?

Answer (score 1):

По аналогии с https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483224/178988 (скрипт из вопроса не менял):

```js
"use strict"; {
  const perlin = {
    init() {
      this.p = new Uint8Array(512);
      this.reset();
    },
    reset() {
      const p = new Uint8Array(256);
      for (let i = 0; i < 256; i++) p[i] = i;
      for (let i = 255; i > 0; i--) {
        const n = Math.floor((i + 1) * Math.random());
        [p[i], p[n]] = [p[n], p[i]];
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < 512; i++) this.p[i] = p[i & 255];
    },
    lerp(t, a, b) {
      return a + t * (b - a);
    },
    grad2d(i, x, y) {
      const v = (i & 1) === 0 ? x : y;
      return (i & 2) === 0 ? -v : v;
    },
    noise2d(x2d, y2d) {
      const X = Math.floor(x2d) & 255;
      const Y = Math.floor(y2d) & 255;
      const x = x2d - Math.floor(x2d);
      const y = y2d - Math.floor(y2d);
      const fx = (3 - 2 * x) * x * x;
      const fy = (3 - 2 * y) * y * y;
      const p0 = this.p[X] + Y;
      const p1 = this.p[X + 1] + Y;
      return this.lerp(
        fy,
        this.lerp(
          fx,
          this.grad2d(this.p[p0], x, y),
          this.grad2d(this.p[p1], x - 1, y)
        ),
        this.lerp(
          fx,
          this.grad2d(this.p[p0 + 1], x, y - 1),
          this.grad2d(this.p[p1 + 1], x - 1, y - 1)
        )
      );
    }
  };
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  const canvas = {
    init() {
      this.elem = document.getElementById("canvas");
      document.body.appendChild(this.elem);
      this.width = this.elem.width = this.elem.offsetWidth;
      this.height = this.elem.height = this.elem.offsetHeight;
      return this.elem.getContext("2d");
    }
  };
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  const webgl = {
    init(canvas, options) {
      this.elem = document.createElement("canvas");
      this.gl = (
        this.elem.getContext("webgl", options) ||
        this.elem.getContext("experimental-webgl", options)
      );
      if (!this.gl) return false;
      const vertexShader = this.gl.createShader(this.gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
      this.gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, `
    precision highp float;
    attribute vec3 aPosition;
    uniform vec2 uResolution;
    void main() {
     gl_PointSize = 1.0;
     gl_Position = vec4(
      ( aPosition.x / uResolution.x * 2.0) - 1.0, 
      (-aPosition.y / uResolution.y * 2.0) + 1.0, 
      0.0,
      1.0
     );
    }`);
      this.gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
      const fragmentShader = this.gl.createShader(this.gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
      this.gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, `
    precision highp float;
    void main() {
     gl_FragColor = vec4(0.07, 0.0, 0.68, 1.0);
    }`);
      this.gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
      const program = this.gl.createProgram();
      this.gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
      this.gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
      this.gl.linkProgram(program);
      this.gl.useProgram(program);
      this.aPosition = this.gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aPosition");
      this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.aPosition);
      this.positionBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();
      this.elem.width = canvas.width;
      this.elem.height = canvas.height;
      const uResolution = this.gl.getUniformLocation(program, "uResolution");
      this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(uResolution);
      this.gl.uniform2f(uResolution, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      this.gl.viewport(
        0,
        0,
        this.gl.drawingBufferWidth,
        this.gl.drawingBufferHeight
      );
      return this.gl;
    },
    drawBuffer(data, num) {
      this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.positionBuffer);
      this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.aPosition, 2, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
      this.gl.bufferData(
        this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
        data,
        this.gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW
      );
      this.gl.drawArrays(this.gl.GL_POINTS, 0, num);
    }
  };
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  const ctx = canvas.init();
  const gl = webgl.init(canvas, {
    alpha: false,
    stencil: false,
    antialias: false,
    depth: false,
  });
  perlin.init();
  const nParticles = 30000;
  const velocities = new Float32Array(nParticles * 2);
  const particles = new Float32Array(nParticles * 2);
  let frame = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < nParticles; i++) {
    const p = i * 2;
    particles[p + 0] = Math.random() * canvas.width;
    particles[p + 1] = Math.random() * canvas.height;
  }
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  const run = () => {
    requestAnimationFrame(run);
    frame++;
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.025)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
    for (let i = 0; i < nParticles; i++) {
      const p = i * 2;
      let n = 80 * perlin.noise2d(particles[p + 0] * 0.001, particles[p + 1] * 0.001);
      velocities[p + 0] += 0.1 * Math.cos(n);
      velocities[p + 1] += 0.1 * Math.sin(n);
      particles[p + 0] += (velocities[p + 0] *= 0.99);
      particles[p + 1] += (velocities[p + 1] *= 0.99);
      particles[p + 0] = (canvas.width + particles[p + 0]) % canvas.width;
      particles[p + 1] = (canvas.height + particles[p + 1]) % canvas.height;
    }
    webgl.drawBuffer(particles, nParticles);
    if (frame > 30) ctx.drawImage(webgl.elem, 0, 0);
  };
  requestAnimationFrame(run);
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ["click", "touchdown"].forEach(event => {
    document.addEventListener(event, e => perlin.reset(), false);
  });
}
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
А тут какой-то текст поверх канваса.
<br>
<a href=http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp>И даже ссылка</a>
```